# How to see how many online users are on my ASP.Net MVC3 website?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

What's the easiest way to see how many users are currently online on my website?

I'd like to display and set this information inside of my _Layout.cshtml file.

I'm using the latest version of ASP.Net MVC3 along with C#.

Comment: What if a user close his browser or navigates away from the site? Is he still considered online?

Comment: @Darin: Ideally, if he doesn't use the site for more than 10 minutes, he's offline according to us. Any suggestions on what to read?

Comment: I figured it out. Since I want to call the information from inside the _Layout.cshtml file and not a View, I had to use: `<span class="onlineusers">Mas de @HttpContext.Current.Application["OnlineUsers"] usuarios en linea!</span>` - Hope this helps someone out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it can be handled in the same way as in ASP.NET.

Main scenario is to increment some static variable or variable in `Application[]` collection on `Session_Start` and decrease this value on `Session_End` to handle number of online users.

Comment: I figured it out. Since I want to call the information from inside the _Layout.cshtml file and not a View, I had to use: `<span class="onlineusers">Mas de @HttpContext.Current.Application["OnlineUsers"] usuarios en linea!</span>` - Hope this helps someone out.

Comment: What about the controller code for "onlineUsers" do you think you could post that as well?

Comment: The comment above shows how to get this information from application state. You can do the same in controller: `HttpContext.Current.Application["OnlineUsers"]`

Answer (score 0):

Application state can be used in this case. Hold a global variable which increments on each new session and decreases on session expiry